# Experience Cloud Partner User unable to @ mention anyone. Chatter is enabled for everyone, chatter is enabled on objects. Any Ideas?

Tags: chatter, experience-cloud, partner-communities

As the question shows I have checked everything I can thing of

- Chatter is enabled
- Chatter Feed Tracking is on for the objects
- User object is Public Read Only for External Users
- Even set up a sharing rule to share users with All Partners
- Made sure users are members of the community

When in the community as a partner user, and I do @ - the only name that can be found is their own name.  Note: I am in the community as Log into Experience as the contact record, but I don't think this would make a difference.

Any other settings I am missing?

Answer (score 0):

I'm no Chatter expert (yet), but perhaps one of these pages could be of use?

- Is the Partner's experience happening on an Experience Cloud Site? If so, double check the Site User Visibility and Portal User Visibility settings in Sharing Settings in Setup. *([Control Which Users Experience Cloud Site Users Can See](https://help.salesforce.com/s/articleView?id=sf.networks_user_sharing.htm&type=5))*
- I'm not quite sure if you're referring to a Private Group with Customers, but if so, Chatter customers can only see people in groups they belong to, and can only see limited profiles. *([Chatter Customers in Private Groups](https://help.salesforce.com/s/articleView?language=en_US&id=sf.collab_external_overview.htm&type=5))*
- You've already mentioned changing the Default External Access of the User object to Public Read Only in Sharing Settings, but a potentially useful troubleshooting tool could be in All Sites > Workspaces > Administration > Preferences, making sure "See other members of this site" has been enabled. *([Site Users were unable to mention internal Users in Chatter](https://help.salesforce.com/s/articleView?id=000381557&type=1))*

Comment: Welcome to Salesforce SE!  This is really a comment, not an answer. With a bit more rep, [you will be able to post comments](//salesforce.stackexchange.com/privileges/comment).